# Addition Calculator in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an addition calculator that checks with an if statement whether the inputs are numbers. However, when I enter non-numeric characters, the alert does not show. Here is my javascript code.

```
function addition() {
  var a = document.getElementById("1st").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("2nd").value;
  var check = /^[0-9]*$/;
  if (!(a.search(check))) {
    window.alert("Please enter only numbers!");
  }     
  var c = Number(a) + Number(b);
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;

}
```

Comment: check.test(a) try this

Answer (score 0):

Simply: BY RegExp

```
function addition() {
  var a = document.getElementById("1st").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("2nd").value;
 var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
  if (!reg.test(a) || !reg.test(b)) 
    window.alert("Please enter only numbers!");
  else{
  var c = Number(a) + Number(b);
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
  }
}
```

Comment: `isNaN` not `isNan`

Comment: @gurvinder372 typo:)

Comment: I am trying to use a regular expression to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addition() {
  var a = document.getElementById("1st").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("2nd").value;
  var check = /^[0-9]*$/;
  if (!check.test(a) || !check.test(b)) {
    window.alert("Please enter only numbers!");
  }     
  else {
    var c = Number(a) + Number(b);
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi A B despite of using regular expression to check number you can use isNaN() javascript function to check whether it is number or not

for example
var x =12;
 isNaN(x) will return false

var x ="char"
isNaN(x) will return true

Comment: var check = /^[0-9]*$/
var x =12
check.test(x) returns true
var y ="char"
check.test(y) returns false

Answer (score 0):

check.test(a) in the condition, if you want to test value a.